# python - ldap3 lib: How to add multiple values to attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

I want to add more than one email adress to a user in ldap. Therefore is an attribut called mailLocalAdress that looks like this when I search/find a specific user with ldapsearch:

```
mailLocalAddress: abc@testing.com
mailLocalAddress: abcd@testing.com
mailLocalAddress: abcdefg@testing.com
```

I'm using python 3, the ldap3 lib and this is how I define the value for the mailLocalAdress attribute

```
ldap_values['mailLocalAddress'] = [user.email_first, user.email_second, user.email_third]
```

and this is the add command

```
ldap_con.add(dn, object_class, ldap_values)
```

and I got this as result when doing ldapsearch

```
mailLocalAddress: ['abc@testing.com', 'abcd@testing.com', 'abcdefg@testing.com']
```

Any ideas how to get the listing above?

Comment: The result you show is what you get when running the `ldapsearch` cli command, or that's the result of performing an ldap search in Python?

Comment: Both results are after running ldapsearch in cli command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you've reported.  If I start with this in my ldap directory:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: example
dc: example

dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalunit
ou: people
```

And then run the following Python code:

```
>>> from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
>>> server=Server('localhost')
>>> conn = Connection(server, user='cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com', password='secret')
>>> conn.bind()
True
>>> dn='uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'
>>> object_class=['person', 'organizationalperson', 'inetorgperson', 'inetlocalmailrecipient']
>>> ldap_values={'sn': 'example', 'cn': 'alice example', 'mailLocalAddress': ['alice@example.com', 'alice.example@example.com']}
>>> conn.add(dn, object_class, ldap_values)
True
>>>
```

An `ldapsearch` returns:

```
/etc/openldap # ldapsearch ... -b dc=example,dc=com uid=alice
# alice, people, example.com
dn: uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
sn: example
cn: alice example
mailLocalAddress: alice@example.com
mailLocalAddress: alice.example@example.com
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: inetLocalMailRecipient
uid: alice
```

Which seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It was a completely different problem:

```
ldap_values = {k: str(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in ldap_values.items()}
```

Before I add the values, I had to convert them to UTF8.
Therefore I convert every value in my dict to string, also the lists!
And of course after this 'brilliant move of mine' the list is treated as string when adding the values to ldap.
I've overlooked this one-liner all along.